# Where is it said I can safely the same local volume to multiple docker containers?

Tags: docker, volume

According to [that StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855234/2363712):

> Yes you can add same location as a volume to many docker containers.

But I read the [Docker Volume documention](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and I can't find where it is said a *local* volume can safely be shared between several containers on the same host. Could someone point me to an official statement regarding that?

Comment: It is the same as sharing the same directory between multiple process. /var/log is usually written into by multiple process in a system.

Comment: Well, what confuses me @Tensibai is volumes are _mounted_ several times. Given the way the Linux kernel handles mounts, it isn't a problem to mount the same device at different locations. But is this just a happy consequence of that, or a supported feature guaranteed to work the same on non-Linux Docker platforms (ie, with Windows Native containers)?

Comment: Technically, they are only mounted once in each container, and at the end of the day, that's not a real mount, that's more a hole in the name spaces where a process in namespace A is allowed to access filesystem in 'host' namespace

Comment: Define "safe". Will it work? Yes. Will you get problems if multiple containers read/write the same set of files? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

By a "local volume" I assume you mean a block device directly attached to the host, such as a "normal" internal disk.

The standard way to run multiple Docker, containers now is Kubernetes, since the demise of Docker Swarm. My reference here is the Kubernetes [documentation for Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) specifically the table on Access Modes, and the column for *ReadWriteMany*. A local volume would be a *HostPath* which is *not* supported for this use case. However if you were using iSCSI it would support *ReadOnlyMany*, and if you used NFS you could get *ReadWriteMany*.

Comment: Searching for the demise of swarm I can only find articles that say that Swarm isn’t demised it is simply that Docker EE will also support k8s. Do you have an official link that says otherwise?